# Parallelizing a serial algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, text-mining

Hej folks,

I am working on porting a Text mining/Natural language application from single-core to a Map-Reduce style system. One of the steps involves a while loop similar to this:

```
Queue<Element>;

while (!queue.empty()) {
    Element e = queue.next();
    Set<Element> result = calculateResultSet(e);

    if (!result.empty()) {
        queue.addAll(result);
    }
}
```

Each iteration depends on the result of the one before (kind of). There is no way of determining the number of iterations this loop will have to perform.

Is there a way of parallelizing a serial algorithm such as this one? I am trying to think of a feedback mechanism, that is able to provide its own input, but how would one go about parallelizing it?

Thanks for any help/remarks

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just partition the work based on the original queue? E.g. is ordering important, is the original queue very short, will there be a huge variance between shortest and longest running time?

Comment: Edvard, the function calculateResultSet() looks at the entire input set, which needs to be completely calculated before this step begins.

Comment: So, with elements added in alphabetical order, with an initial list of `[a,b,c]`, `a` will evaluate `[b,c]`, `b` will evaluate `[b,c,d,e]` (for example) etc.? Can `calculateResultSet` start processing with incomplete data (i.e. can it process the queue up until when the next part is ready)? I'm not sure how it would fit into the MapReduce paradigm, but it seems like (maybe) all the initial elements can start processing their partial list until `a` finishes, then process `a` until `b` finishes and so on.

Comment: From what I know about the application so far, `calculateResultSet()` needs the entire set to be ready, so there isn't really a way to start with a half-finished set.
What I need would be a way to append to the input of a Map-Operation, but I don't believe that's possible.

Comment: Can you modify `calculateResultSet`? If you can't, and the Nth call to `calculateResultSet` requires the complete results for the N-1 previous calls to start processing, then you're stuck with serial execution. If you can modify `calculateResultSet`, you could parallelize that, or process data until the end of the avaliable queue and wait, processing data as it is produced by the previous executions, and only returning results when all N-1 previous outputs are processed.

Comment: Yes, i can modify all parts of the application, including that function. `calculateResultSet` looks at the remaining items in the queue, modifies some of them and then possibly returns a few that are then appended to the input queue. I don't see how it would be possible to parallelize that. Maybe you do?

Comment: I see two ways that can be parallelized, but they both involve the queue being processed in parts (e.g. splitting the queue into N parts, and running them in parallel). But it relies on the `b` part of the queue being able to process `c` before `a` finishes, so if `a` can modify `c` before `b` can process `c`, then maybe some sort of speculative execution could work, but it's hard to say without knowing what `calculateResultSet` actually does.

Comment: Maybe there's some sort of stopping criterion one could use to determine whether an operation can occur or not?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could split `calculateResultSet` into several different functions that operate on the entire set. This way, you could give all the functions the entire set and have each function perform a separate operation. Once all functions have completed, you can then feed all the results to another function to create the final output. This would allow you to send the data to different nodes, perform an operation, and finally gather the results using a distributed architecture.

You could also look into the notion of sharing. A classic example is the fibonacci sequence where xn is dependent on xn-1 and xn-2. Here is an example of a parallelized version using OpenMP: http://myxman.org/dp/node/182

Answer (score 1):

Mstoeckli's suggestion is a good one. Alternatively, if your data is really large, maybe it's possible to do do divide up the dataset and do your loop for various pieces of the set, and then recombine the data at a predetermined number of iterations (or after some sort of stopping criterion).

You'll need to experiment a little bit- some problems tend to be fine even with a lot of approximation, others not at all.